# Discrepancy when computing an address' balance from transaction history vs calling the getBalance RPC method?

Tags: transactions, rpc

For some addresses, if you call `getSignaturesForAddress` to get its entire transaction history and sum up all of the balance changes (via calculating `postBalances[i]` - `preBalances[i]`) you almost always end up with a number that's slightly larger (about 0.0006 SOL or more) than if you simply call `getBalance` from an RPC node.

Does anyone know why this discrepancy might exist? Rent? Hidden fees?

Comment: Could it also be that there's a lot of txs going on for these accounts and it's just timing out?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely ignoring the rent-exempt amount when computing getBalance. However the rent exemption is about 0.00089088, so I'm not sure why you would get 0.0006

Answer (score 0):

Things you might be doing wrong.

You need to add the difference to a `balance` that you initialize at 0

```
let balance = 0
loop transactions {
   balance += postBalances[i] - preBalances[i]
}
```

**And make sure the `i` you choosing is the wallet you're trying to extract the balance each time**. Order of the accounts changes

And finally, make sure you extract all the Transactions. for `getSignaturesForAddress`

`the limit: <number> - maximum transaction signatures to return (between 1 and 1,000, default: 1,000).`

So you need to do 2 requests if you have over 1000 transactions. Specify the last transaction signature in `before: <string> - start searching backward from this transaction signature. If not provided the search starts from the top of the highest max confirmed block.`

[More information here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturesforaddress)

Comment: yeah doing all of these already but no luck — thinking it has something to do with rent and rent-exempt accounts

Comment: I have not idea if this is anyhow connected but I have got recently a strange observation around the balances: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/sol-transfer-fee-calculation