# SOL transfer fee calculation

Tags: transfer, solana-test-validator

I experience a strange behavior of the SOL transfer.

I use Typescript `@solana/web3.js` client that do SOL transfer from local wallet filled with SOLs automatically at `solana-test-validator` start. Then the amount of `890880` is transfered to another account.
My expectation is that the spent amount on this operation from my wallet is the transfered amount + fee (which is 5000 lamports for a signature).
But the difference between account balance before and after transfer is not `5000+890880=895880` but it's `895860`. It's like there in sum 20 lamports more in the network after transfer.

I ran some testing with `solana-test-validator` `1.14.10` and I've got test issues coming from balance differences from expected behavior. I cannot understand what's the issue. If it's some precision rounding of Typescript client or BN library or if it's some rounding trick in Solana/Cli?

I have a simple reproducer here:
https://github.com/ochaloup/solana-transfer-reproducer

Answer (score 1):

you may forget to consider other source of fees. Fees does not only take in consideration the number of signatures but also for instance the number of compute units which have been used, please see : https://docs.solana.com/transaction_fees

Comment: That's the good point and I thought if it's caused by that. But it does not seems so. I do not set any priority fee or changes default CUs. And when I transfer another amount of SOL (like 1 SOL) the balance matches the transferred amount plus fee for one signature. I tried a bit more and if I send the same amount but from account with smaller starting balance then again all sums matches.